# How Save the Client Tokens To use More Times

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api, cookies, client, token

for example: if i have Asp.net web Api Application and this application get a Token from Client To send Notification for this Client with this Token and every Client have a different Token.
How can I save this Token for each individual Client To every Client use his Special Token more Times from different Computer or From different Browser??

Schould I use cookies or Session or is there something else??

It is worth noting that the Token is sent from the client and used by the server

Answer (score 1):

The WebAPi is a Stateless Project that mean you do not need to manage the state for every client!

For example, if you use JWT token, once the token created by API, client must send the token for every request.

BUT

If you need to save a token for more use!

Four options come to mind :
1-use your primary db(ex:SQL Server) to save the token!and retrieve every time you need!(Not a good idea)

2-save your token to Redis!

3-create a static class with Singleton lifetime, then with dictionary you can save the token for every client to memory!

4-Use In-memory Database [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)